# Need help in an array

Tags: android

I have a string str and I want to take the string and put it in the `int[] xAxis` array.How can I do that? The following code should work but does not. What am I doing wrong? Need help.Thanks

```
String str = 12,16,23,78;

String[] nums = str.split(",");
int[] newArr = new int[nums.length];

for(int i = 0;i < newArr.length;i++)
{
    newArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);

    int results = newArr[i];

}

int[] xAxis = new int[]{results};
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It would be helpful if you can explain why it isn't working. 

Right off the bat I would say that you should take note that your final nums element will be 78; which probably won't work in parseInt. 

Also I'm guessing it's an error from typing up the sample but results is declared inside the for loop so it can't be used to set the xAxis.

Comment: How should I set the results so that xAxis has access to it?

Comment: You can declare xAxis before your for loop and set the results directly in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this

```
int[] xAxis = new int[nums.length];

for(int i = 0;i < newArr.length;i++)
{
    xAxis[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
}
```